# Use of die() in flow control - proper and sensible?

Tags: php, xml

Designed for OpenCart, vQmod places or replaces bits of code based on `XML` files.

The following three versions of the code achieve the same goal, which is to replace nearly ALL of a specific page.

The `offset` parameter tells the vqmod how many lines of code to remove, including and following the `search` code.

It seems to me that the one that simply uses `die()` following the `footer()` is the most sensible because it leaves room for core file length change and isn't referencing a non-existent vQmod `offset`, but is there anything wrong with doing it that way?

```
    <operation info="Block users from checking out">
        <search position="replace" offset="963"><![CDATA[<h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[  <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
            <h2>Order will be processed after the food shipment has arrived.</h2>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Shopping carts are automatically saved, so please just set the contents of your shopping cart to match your desired order.</p>
            <p>Remember that prices are approximate and item availability is not guaranteed.</p>
            <?php echo $footer;?>]]>
        </add>
    </operation>
```

But what if the next core update has a longer file? We could also just `die()` at the end of the code we place:

```
    <operation info="Block users from checking out">
        <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[  <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
            <h2>Order will be processed after the food shipment has arrived.</h2>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Shopping carts are automatically saved, so please just set the contents of your shopping cart to match your desired order.</p>
            <p>Remember that prices are approximate and item availability is not guaranteed.</p>
            <?php echo $footer;
            die();?>]]>
        </add>
    </operation>
```

Another option is to increase the `offset` to a number that seems likely to encompass any likely increases to line numbers in the (near) future:

```
    <operation info="Block users from checking out">
        <search position="replace" offset="1000"><![CDATA[<h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[  <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
            <h2>Order will be processed after the food shipment has arrived.</h2>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Shopping carts are automatically saved, so please just set the contents of your shopping cart to match your desired order.</p>
            <p>Remember that prices are approximate and item availability is not guaranteed.</p>
            <?php echo $footer;?>]]>
        </add>
    </operation>
```